# why is shape-indexed-feature so effective on face alignment?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, face-recognition

I am implementing some face alignment algorithm recently. I have read the following papers:

- [Supervised descent method and its applications to face alignment](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590v/13au/intraface.pdf)
- [Face alignment by explicit shape regression](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/192097/cvpr12_facealignment.pdf)
- [Face alignment at 3000 fps via regressing local binary features](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~sqren/FaceAlignment/FaceAlignment_LocalBinaryFeatures.pdf)

All the paper mentioned a important keyword: `shape-indexed-feature` or `pose-indexed-feature`. This feature plays a key role in face alignment process. I did not get the key point of this feature. Why is it so important?

Comment: unfortunately, all your links are behind a paywall

Comment: sorry! I change them to free link now!

Comment: It's not exactly a programming question, but it's an interesting one...

Comment: aren't both 'shape-indexed-feature' and 'pose-indexed-feature' just other words for 'facial landmarks' ? (or say, a model build from that ?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A shape-indexed-feature is a feature who's index gives some clue about the hierarchical structure of the shape that it came from. So in face alignment, facial landmarks are extremely important, since they are the things that will be useful in successfully aligning the faces. But, just taking facial landmarks into account throws away some of the structure inherent to a face. You know that the pupil is inside the iris, which is inside the eye. So a shape-indexed-feature would do more than tell you that you are looking at a facial landmark - it would tell you that you are looking at  a facial landmark inside another landmark inside another landmark. Because there are only a few features that are 3-nested like that, you can be more confident about aligning those correctly.

Here is a much older paper that explains some of this with simpler language (especially in the introduction): http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/cvpr97.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> If you want get shape-indexed-feature, you should do similarity transform for the face landmarks in one image first. The aim is transform the origin landmarks to a specific location which could be the mean landmark of all images. So the landmarks of each image is at same position.
>
> Then you could extract local features according to the relocate landmarks, which are shape-indexed-feature, cause now the landmarks of each image is a fix shape.

I seached hours get the answer above, a [graduation thesis](https://max.book118.com/html/2017/0604/111603504.shtm) and translated it, but not sure whether it's a right answer or not. In my opinion, it make sense.